# XeTeX and GraphicX

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf

When processing with XeLaTeX, some .pdf (I really don't know the difference between them) files give the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in xxxx.pdf (no BoundingBox).
! LaTeX Error: Can not include graphics of type: pdf.
```

I am using `graphicx` with the `[xetex]` option, but to no avail. I'm using the following:

```
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)
kpathsea version 6.0.1
Compiled with ICU version 4.6 [with modifications for XeTeX]
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.5; using 1.2.5
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.4.4; using 2.4.4
Using Mac OS X Carbon, Cocoa & QuickTime frameworks
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems the problem is in the includegraphics options I was using:

```
\includegraphics[type=pdf,ext=.pdf,read=.pdf,scale=0.6]{xxxx}
```

The following seems to work fine:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{xxxx}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `type` and so on. XeLaTeX looks for the file name with the extensions `.pdf`, `.eps`, `.ps`, `.png`, `.jpg`, `.bmp`, `.pict`, `.tif`, `.psd`, `.mac`, `.sga`, .tga`, and `.gif` in this order.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with texstudio

> !LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in xxxx.pdf (no
>   BoundingBox).

The error was caused because the "build & view" was set "**dvi**->pdf chain".

The **solution** is to set

configuration->build->build & view->**compile & view**

or "**pdf** chain".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I just discovered is that filenames that include an extra dot (`.`) in their name, not including the dot before the file extension will throw this error in XeTeX. I had a series of PDF plots produced with a function in R, and `pdfinfo` showed identical size statistics for all of them, but those with an extra dot in their filenames had issues with determining their size. So another possible fix if you've tried everything else is to see if your filename has more than just the dot before the filename extension.